# Problems forming a URL with arguments in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arguments, fetch

I have made a database connection in php and FETCH parts like story and id.
the URL forms ok without '&' but fails when '&' is added in the URL.

Here is my php code with '&id=' added in the URL

```
$fullurl = /cms/page.php . '?chapter=' . $row['story'] . '&id=' . $row['id'];
```

Can someone put me right about the correct syntax...

Comment: What you mean by OK and FAILS? What is the error

Comment: the mysql and sql tags are completely irrelevant for this question, please consider removing them.

Comment: Did you not get any error

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious

```
$fullurl = /cms/page.php . '?chapter=' . $row['story'] . '&id=' . $row['id'];
```

should be changed so that all text is within the citation marks..

```
$fullurl = '/cms/page.php?chapter=' . $row['story'] . '&id=' . $row['id'];
```

Otherwise you will end up in an error.

Also please, consider using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> The part: `/cms/page.php` is not a string.... and thus is wrong. You could just change it to something like this:

```
<?php 
     // NOTICE THAT THE PART "/cms/page.php" IS NOW EMBEDDED IN QUOTES (STRING)
    $fullurl = "/cms/page.php" . '?chapter=' . $row['story'] . '&id=' . $row['id'];

    // OR EVEN COMPACT IT LIKES SO:
    $fullurl = "/cms/page.php?chapter=" . $row['story'] . '&id=' . $row['id'];
```

Comment: @alankeys   It is safe to presume that that Errors is something else altogether and has nothing to do with the URL

Comment: fails error message: 
error on line 12 at column 85: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Comment: @alankeys how does Line 12, Column 85 look like in your Code?.... Seems like you had a typo on that line or failed to close a Statement with a  Semi-Colon ( **;** )

Comment: line 12 also looks like the example given in my posting... (with citation marks accordingly)

Comment: @alankeys   Yeah.... but ***check the codes before that line.***  Sometimes in PHP, the real Error is not really the reported Error. You should definitely look above that Line to see where what went wrong in your code....

Comment: $all = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT story,id FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = ", $id);

Comment: @alankeys   Think  we caught a GOTCHA here: That code should read: `$all = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT story.id FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = " . $id);` After `WHERE id = " ` You accidentally added a COMMA instead of a DOT :-)

Comment: still hasnt worked poiz....  also is that meant to be a comma between story and id  ?     error message is....

Comment: SELECT story,id FROM news30_story WHERE id = Arguments: Array ( )

Comment: has anyone any ideas about this....
    DataAccess::fetch("SELECT story.id FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = " . $id);
or
    DataAccess::fetch("SELECT story,id FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = " . $id);
has not solved it...

Comment: @alankeys Is `NEWS_ARTCLES` a Constant? If not, try: `$all = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT story.id FROM NEWS_ARTICLES WHERE id = " . $id);`

Comment: poiz...   i want to add more code. just trying to work out how to do this.

Comment: Poiz...code added as an answer to main posting. Please see my actual code.

Comment: . '&#38;' . 'id=' . $row['id'];

Answer (score 0):

poiz

it still didnt work but i found i dont need to fetch from NEWS_ARTICLES. In fact my variables are already fetched as you see below...

Here is my actual code.

```
$sql = "SELECT old,title,story,shortstory,author,origauthor,ip,timestamp,allowcomments,short,approved,viewcount,rating,archive date,neverarchive,archived,id, 
" . NEWS_USERS . ".user AS authorname, 
" . NEWS_USERS . ".avatar AS authoravatar, 
commentcount AS comments
FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " INNER JOIN " . NEWS_USERS . " ON " . NEWS_ARTICLES . ".author = " . NEWS_USERS . ".uid WHERE id IN (";
    if($nocats == "1"){
        $sql .= "SELECT id AS storyid FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT storyid FROM " . NEWS_GROUPCATS . " WHERE type = 'news') UNION ";
    }          
$sql .= "SELECT storyid FROM " . NEWS_GROUPCATS . " WHERE type = 'news' AND catid IN (SELECT catid FROM " . NEWS_GROUPCATS . " WHERE type = 'rss' AND storyid = ?) ) AND archived = '0' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, $rssamount";   
$newsstories = DataAccess::fetch($sql, $feedid);
foreach($newsstories AS $row){

    if(FRIENDLY){
        $fullurl = $newslocation . $prefix . $row['id'] . "-0-" . makefriendly($row[title]);
    }else{
        $fullurl = $newslocation . '?epic-code=' . $row['shortstory'] . '&id=' . $row['id']; 
    }
```

'&id'   gives...
error on line 12 at column 85: EntityRef: expecting ';'

'id'    gives...
[a link] http://www.example.com//stock-charts/share-charts.php?epic-code=ALTPid=3360

the & is missing ....